# Want to fetch more than 2 id from table in asp.net using sql server

Tags: sql, asp.net

while fetching id form table it returns field name not the column value

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("Select ShowId,ScreenId,MovieId,MenuId FROM tbl_Booking WHERE BookingId ='"+ 7 +"'",con);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    string ShowId = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ShowId"].ToString();
    string ClassId = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ClassId"].ToString();
    string ScreenId = ds.Tables[0].Columns["ScreenId"].ToString();
    string MovieId = ds.Tables[0].Columns["MovieId"].ToString();
    string MenuId = ds.Tables[0].Columns["BookedMenuId"].ToString();
```

Comment: Please add some text to describe your Problem\

Comment: while fetching id from table its show only field name not the value

Comment: Please edit your Question accordingly

Comment: That means your SQL server is not having data as per your select statement with condition `BookingId = 7` - please give the SQL data structure and sample data for your table `tbl_Bookking`

Comment: the sql server is having data that's why i have select statemnent condition BookingId=7. I have checked database table and created query where BookingId=7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting value from rows instead columns change your code like this

```
ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["ShowId"].ToString();
```

if you have only one row  and if multiple use foreach loop.